# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+ , Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio, I tried everything to solve this problem "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+ "

I tried to clean project , invalidate cash/restart and removing .idea and still the same

I'm using android studio 2.2.1 for a learning reason , and I updated it to android studio 3 and there a multiple rendering problems so I returned back to version 2.2.1

I tried to add

maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }

So,It stuck with another problem

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'"
```

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtCjq.png)

Finally I tried to change "appcompat-v7:28.+" to "appcompat-v7:27" and it' works but still tell me that i should use the same library to avoid mistakes

This is my Gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aimlive.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Replace `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28+'` by `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

and add below dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

try adding this to your code:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    }
}
```

Update: Now you moved on to another error:

> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable ...

To fix this, you need to change `compile` to `implementation` in `dependencies` part.

Comment: I tried , It shows this problem "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'"

Comment: @AhmedHassan Now you moved on to another problem. I updated the answer.

Comment: @AhmedHassan If this answer helped you, you can accept it to make it easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
```

add in your dependencies below code

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha'
```

this is the [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0-alpha1)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, hope it is working

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

dependencies

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

android

```
  compileSdkVersion 28
  minSdkVersion 21
  targetSdkVersion 28
```

Comment: Worked! I thought these two were incompatible:implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' ...I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it will be working. Thanks

build.gradle (Project)

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

}

dependencies check for implementation

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found that 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable' and 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable' have a same package name in support library version 28.0.0. Normally this does not make the problem.

But if you have the following line in gradle.properties

`android.uniquePackageNames = true`

you will see the error

`more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'"`

If you should use the uniquePackageNames option, use androidx instead of support library 28.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
        In case someone like me stuck for hours and find out the you have to check the maven dependency "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0". remove the "+" sign as gradle does not like it for unpredictable versions. so i had to check the maven repository and found that i was compiling with 29 and 29 does not exist. please check below link
[""][1]

        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.example.amirkhan.birthday"
                minSdkVersion 15
                targetSdkVersion 28
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {

            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

        }

    2)) Maven should be included.
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            google()
        }
    }


    Wallah the problem is solved


  [1]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0
```

Comment: Try to explain what your code is atleast in one line.

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' and you should include  maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.